I had a corrupt cache file i deleted then restored it. Reinstalled android studio and restarted my project but i get this error. How can i solve it?
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kspDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Internal compiler error. See log for more details

How do i solve it? The buid is failing

Please include the log so we can see what went wrong.

try File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
